# #2002 Connexion to MySQL server not allowed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress, mysql-error-2002

I've a Wordpress MU and when the website shows Error database connexion.

the Mysql is not furnished by my OVH hosting and when I look at wp-config.php I've user and password and when I got to mysite.com//phpMyAdmin-4.1.1-all-languages/

I've #2002 Connexion to MySQL server not allowed

How can I get my website back online.

Thanks for your help
Franck

Comment: this should probably be posted over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or at least tagged wordpress

Answer (score 0):

1.go into phpMyAdmin directory
2.cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php